# Two way binding angularjs service bug

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Take the following fiddle:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ne5P8/2318/)

Now in this code you will see the following line:

```
 newList.forEach(function(y){
      activeUsers.push(y);
    });
```

This works perfectly fine.  however change the code to:

```
activeUsers = newList;
```

And the code no longer works.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening and how i might  fix it so the two way binding works?

Comment: Any particular reason this fiddle is using a 4-years-old RC version of Angular?

Comment: @FélixSaparelli No not really it was a template of angular i found but i promise you its the same in the current version of angular

Comment: @Vineet im not quite sure what you mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That doesn't work because you change the reference. Your old `$scope.activeUsers` still points to the same old empty array.

After you change the reference, you'll have to get the new reference back from the factory. That's why changing the reference will cause you issues.

If you take the reference from the factory, like you do, then you'll have to keep working on that same array if you want all the bindings to work as you expect.

Comment: can you give an example on how i might update the value in an elegant way then?

Comment: @MarcRasmussen Btw I've added a splicing line of code for the array in case you'll recall the `setActiveUsers`, you probably want the array to reset: http://jsfiddle.net/Ne5P8/2324/

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.activeUsers = testFactory.getActiveUsers();
```

You assign the array ref to $scope.activeUsers. so if you push some element to activeUsers, $scope.activeUsers will change also.

```
activeUsers = newList;
```

Then if you do this, activeUsers point to another array ref, so at this time, $scope.activeUsers is not same as activeUsers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know a way i can create the binding "correctly" for it to work?